# PaperJS targeting shape

Tags: javascript, event-handling, paperjs

I'm making a Patatap clone, and trying to make different shapes and different animations on each key.

I've figured how to assign different shapes on `onKeyDown` function, but I'm stuck at `onFrame` function to give different animations on each shape.

I tried to check the array of shapes to find out the difference, but since it has tons of lines, I was not able to.

```
//Just short dummy code to roughly show how I did

function onKeyDown(event){
 if(type === 'rectangle'){
  var shape = new Path.Rectangle
 }else if(type === 'circle'){
  var shape = new Path.Circle
 }
}
... this works

function onFrame(event){
 shape.fillColor.hue += 1; //this works


 //I want to do this
 //shape.type is just a made up variable

 if(shape.type === 'rectangle'){
  shape.rotate(5);
 }else if(shape.type === 'circle'){
  shape.scale(0.95);
}
```

Thanks for any help

[demo link](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)

Comment: you have a type at the last line `scalce`. Can you make a sketch on http://sketch.paperjs.org ? That will be much better to help you ; we need more code to understand and help you.

Comment: @arthur.sw thanks! didn't know there's such thing. I just added it

Comment: ok, so I guess your question is "how can I know that this shape is a Rectangle or a Circle to make a transform according to this type?"?

Comment: In theory in javascript you could use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) (if(`shape[i] instanceof Path.Circle)`) but I just tried and it does not work, so you can just add a name property to your shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Path.data` property to add things you need for your logic, I updated your nice [demo](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) by adding a `name` property giving the type of the shape.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! that was exactly what I needed.